# Copying data from MySQL to Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in MySQL Containing 500 million records. I want to import this table to Amazon DynamoDB.I understand there are two ways to do it:

1. JAVA Api: The problem with this approach is that it is slow, also the connection to database gets dropped sometimes.
2. Amazon Data Import Pipeline : Seems promising, But how do I export the data from MySQL to the format recognized by DynamoDB?

Please let me the best possible approach between the two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AWS has two services that can help you to perform that operation.

- Data Pipeline
- EMR cluster with Hive

**Data Pipeline**

A very simple way - if your "schemas" are similar (I always feel awkward to talk about schema for DynamoDB) - would be to export from MySQL to S3, then to import from S3 to DynamoDB.

Data Pipeline has two Tutorials to help you to setup thee tasks

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-copydata-mysql.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part1.html

You can further improve this process by developing a single pipeline that perform the import and the export.  Should you need to transform the data between the import and export, you will need to develop your transformation code and execute it from the pipeline.

In Data Pipeline terms, this is call an Activity.  An activity might be as simple as a shell script or as complex as a Hive / Hadoop / Pig application running on an EMR closer.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-concepts-activities.html

Data Pipeline will also let you schedule your execution at regular time interval.

**Hive and EMR**

Hive is an hadoop tool to write SQL commands to manipulate data sources.  Hive translate the SQL in an Hadoop application which is run on a cluster.
You can run Hive on AWS Elastic Map Reduce Cluster (a managed service hadoop cluster).

Hive on EMR can connect to non relation data sources, such as files on S3 or DynamoDB database.  It allows you to write SQL statements on top of DynamoDB !

In your use case, you need to write an Hive script that would read from MySQL and write to DynamoDB.  You can transform the data using standard (Hive) SQL expressions.

More about Hive on EMR :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hive.html

More about DynamoDB and Hive :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.Walkthrough.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/EMRforDynamoDB.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the easiest way for me was to write a script to transfer all information into a json file in the format specified here : [AWS Load Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SampleData.LoadData.html)

```
{
    "ProductCatalog": [
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "Id": {
                        "N": "101"
                    },
                    "Title": {
                        "S": "Book 101 Title"
                    },
                    "ISBN": {
                        "S": "111-1111111111"
                    },
                    "Authors": {
                        "L": [
                            {
                                "S": "Author1"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "Price": {
                        "N": "2"
                    },
                    "Dimensions": {
                        "S": "8.5 x 11.0 x 0.5"
                    },
                    "PageCount": {
                        "N": "500"
                    },
                    "InPublication": {
                        "BOOL": true
                    },
                    "ProductCategory": {
                        "S": "Book"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "Id": {
                        "N": "103"
                    },
                    "Title": {
                        "S": "Book 103 Title"
                    },
                    "ISBN": {
                        "S": "333-3333333333"
                    },
                    "Authors": {
                        "L": [
                            {
                                "S": "Author1"
                            },
                            {
                                "S": "Author2"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "Price": {
                        "N": "2000"
                    },
                    "Dimensions": {
                        "S": "8.5 x 11.0 x 1.5"
                    },
                    "PageCount": {
                        "N": "600"
                    },
                    "InPublication": {
                        "BOOL": false
                    },
                    "ProductCategory": {
                        "S": "Book"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "Id": {
                        "N": "205"
                    },
                    "Title": {
                        "S": "18-Bike-204"
                    },
                    "Description": {
                        "S": "205 Description"
                    },
                    "BicycleType": {
                        "S": "Hybrid"
                    },
                    "Brand": {
                        "S": "Brand-Company C"
                    },
                    "Price": {
                        "N": "500"
                    },
                    "Color": {
                        "L": [
                            {
                                "S": "Red"
                            },
                            {
                                "S": "Black"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "ProductCategory": {
                        "S": "Bicycle"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and then create the tables and run the code from my console

```
aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://ProductCatalog.json
```

To download and configure aws cli :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.CLI.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answer, I would like to mention that dynamodb recognizes `csv` or `tsv` format files for importing. We can also use HIVE sql using Elastic Map Reduce to bulk load data from a `csv` file. The only thing we need to consider is - if we use windows to dump table to `csv`  then we must make sure that the line ending of windows system `\r\n` be replaced by `\n` to make it compliant with amazon.

Comment: Thank you to complete my answer @Prabhu.  I mentioned HIVE as well.  Please notice that converting \r\n to \n is not an amazon requirement but \n is the standard for line termination for Unix systems and Linux.

Comment: which is always a pain! everywhere

Answer (score -1):

If you have a portal like *PhpMyAdmin* you can easily **export** your data to a **JSON** format.

[image: how to export]

Next you create the table manually.

Finally, with [Dynabase](https://dynobase.dev/) you can import JSON files to DynamoDB tables. Even though Dynabase is a commercial tool, it does unlock all required features even with the trial license.

The MySQL JSON export sometimes also stores additional information about the table. If necessary, I do edit the file manually to just keep the data-portion of the file. The JSON files that I import have an array in their root, e.g.

```
[ 
  { "id": 1 , "foo" : "bar" }, 
  { "id": 361, "foo" : "baz" } 
]
```

[image: Dynobase]

You probably don't need to convert the format of your data.